# Saving picture from clipBoard c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

so ive been messing around with saveing an image from the clipboard after you hit prtscn. now the problem that I have ran in to is the code below is slow. i have tried to onle save one image, its a little faster when i do that. but their is still a noticable lag when it saves the picture..

```
 if (Clipboard.GetDataObject() != null)
        {
            IDataObject data = Clipboard.GetDataObject();

            if (data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Bitmap))
            {
                Image image = (Image)data.GetData(DataFormats.Bitmap, true);

                image.Save("image.bmp", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
                image.Save("image.jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                image.Save("image.gif", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("The Data In Clipboard is not as image format");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("The Clipboard was empty");
        }
```

Comment: The code itself runs fast here, so it may be your storage device?

Comment: @okrumnow *sigh* compleatly forgot ive been building and running this off my usb.. thanks tho